# Can a Boost.asio endpoint be used to identify a client over time for UDP connections?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

In a client/server application, my client connects to the server via UDP using [Boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

The server opens its socket like this:

```cpp
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket;
socket
  ( _ioService,
     boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint
       ( boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), port ) );
```

The client opens its socket like this:

```cpp
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket;
socket( _ioService );
socket.open( boost::asio::ip::udp::v4() );
```

Then when a client sends its first message to the server, the server uses the client endpoint as an identifier for future messages. Here is a simplification of the identification process:

```
class Server
{
private:
  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket;
  boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint receiveEndpoint;

private:
  void waitIncoming()
  {
    socket.async_receive_from
      ( boost::asio::null_buffers(), receiveEndpoint,
        boost::bind( &Server::messageReceived, this ) );
  }

  void messageReceived()
  {
    registerClient( receiveEndpoint );
  }
}
```

Since the client uses the same socket instance from the beginning to the end of its work, is it safe for the server to use the endpoint as an identifier of the client?

Comment: what part of the receiveEndpoint do you use as identification? There's addresses and ports *in my limited understanding of UDP) too. Addresses can be equivalent even if not identical (depending on name resolutions/routing) and ports will change on reconnection. If you need a 'session ID' in a non-stream connection, why don't you include the id in the protocol?

Comment: I use [operator==](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint/operator_eq__eq_.html) to compare the endpoints. I don't know if Boost.asio use something else than the address and the port to compare the endpoints. If it does, I don't know if the port can change over the lifetime of the socket on the client. If the endpoint is not an identifier I will add a session ID, but if it is I would like to avoid adding redundant stuff in the protocol.

Comment: Whether you can or cannot rely on the endpoint being "equal" depends only on your application requirements. I suggest you just explicitly code your intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A boost [IP endpoint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint.html) at least identifies 3 of the 5 values that uniquely identify a UDP connection: `protocol (UDP)`, `source IP`, `source port`. If your server uses only one `dest IP`/`dest port` or you add these parameters yourself or this does not matter, then yes you can use this as some sort of session identifier. A few gotchas though:

- This is only realistic during some application-specific transaction. For example, in a file transfer client, it might be that you setup a new connection for every file. Also, a single client might use parallel connections to speed things up making your life harder. This is not even UDP specific, TCP has the same issue.
- Deleting the session/identifier is extremely hard. UDP has no explicit disconnect as TCP has, so you have to use some idle timeout. However, put this too short and you might remove the identifier to soon, put this too long and an actually *new* connection might be identified as an *old* one.

In general, establishing a session concept is usually better done on application level, e.g. generate a random [UUID4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) and prefix that to every packet. Problem one is solved by specifying that the client must reuse this identifier. Problem two is solved because it's unlikely that any client will ever use the same UUID, so you can actually use quite a large timeout.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your client application. It needs to open a port locally and send a datagram to your server. The client can either bind to a specific local port or let the operating system choose a free local port at random. As long as the socket is bound to the local UDP port, the port number won't change. However, if the client chooses to close the socket after sending a datagram and if it does not explicitly bind to the same local port for the next datagram it is about to send, the operating system is free to choose a totally different port.

When the client is behind a router with NAT, it might also happen that the source port is rewritten and there is no guarantee that this port number will stay stable for any amount of time.

So while it might work most of the time, I would not rely on the behavior outside a controlled environment. You might switch to a connection based protocol (TCP) or use own session IDs. The latter might be tricky, because you'll need to manage them possibly even across program restarts to prevent double IDs and add some checks to prevent session hijacking if that's an issue for you.

Comment: That would be one broken client, how would response packets ever reach it? Same goes for the NAT implementation. Theoretically good arguments, but I don't think they're realistic.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about the server ever responding and there are realistic scenarios where the clients periodically send data and never receive anything back (e.g. smart temperature sensors or the like). When receiving a new datagram the next day, it cannot be guaranteed that the source IP and ports are still the same (e.g. due to short DHCP lease times). It might also happen that a different client has the same IP/port as another client had the day before. Not necessarily highly probable, but also not impossible.

Comment: yes, but that is with much more restrictions than your answer says (it makes those issues look very generic). I actually say the same thing in my answer, we're aligned there.